# Making 2 words (uppercase and lowercase) from 1 word

Tags: c, string

I did a program which gets the word **"SHaddOW"** and dividing it to 2 words: `SHOW` and `add`.

That is one word of uppercase characters and the other word of lowercase chars. But I have some problem when I'm running the program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int countbig = 0 , countsmall = 0;
    char str[] = "SHaddOW";
    char smallStr[SIZE] , bigStr[SIZE]; 
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str) ; i++)
    {
        if (str[i]>= 'A' && str[i]<='Z')
        {
            bigStr[countbig] = str[i];
            countbig++;
        }
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            smallStr[countsmall] = str[i];
            countsmall++;
        }
    }
    puts(smallStr);
    puts(bigStr);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm running the program its showing that:

[image]

Comment: Not related, but you are missing `#include <stdio.h>`. Compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Change `i <= strlen(str)` to `i < strlen(str)` and add the null character at the end of each word.

Comment: Or better yet, don't call `strlen` of the constant source string in the loop. Check for the termonating null char: `for (i = 0; str[i] ; i++)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
puts( smallStr );
```

This keeps on writing whatever `smallStr` is pointing to, until it hits a null byte (`'\0'`).

You never write a null byte into either `smallStr` or `bigStr`, so you see the garbled output you are observing. (Be happy the program did not crash, as it is accessing memory it should not.)

At the end of the loop, terminate the strings:

```
smallStr[ countsmall ] = '\0';
bigStr[ countbig ] = '\0';
```

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because of not doing null termination so ,
Do initialization for

```
 char smallStr[SIZE] = {0} , bigStr[SIZE] = {0};
```

**or**

Do the null termination after loop completed at end of loop do

```
smallStr[ countsmall ] = '\0';
bigStr[ countbig ] = '\0';
```

You will get correct result.

Comment: @DevSolar: Why not? It sets all chars to null and provided the string doesn't overflow (which the OP doesn't check) will leave a proper null-terminated string.

Comment: @MOehm: That "and all the remaining elements" zero initialization keeps getting me on the wrong foot. Comment deleted, downvote retracted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #define SIZE 10

    int main()
    {
         int i = 0;
         int countbig = 0 , countsmall = 0;
         char str[] = "SHaddOW";
         char smallStr[SIZE] , bigStr[SIZE]; 
         for (i = 0; i < strlen(str) ; i++)
         {
             if (str[i]>= 'A' && str[i]<='Z')
             {
               bigStr[countbig] = str[i];
               countbig++;
             }
             else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
             {
              smallStr[countsmall] = str[i];
              countsmall++;
             }
         }
         bigStr[countbig]='\0';
         smallStr[countsmall] = '\0';

         puts(smallStr);
         puts(bigStr);
         system("PAUSE");
         return 0;
  }
```

You should add `\0` to end the string and only travel till `i` is less than length of the string.

Comment: When answering you should indent the code correctly.

Comment: is it fine  Michael ?

Comment: It's fine now, except the last line where the `}` is not aligned correctly. Also the indent size is not constant.  Remember, consistent formatting of your code is most important for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int countbig = 0 , countsmall = 0;
    char str[] = "SHaddOW";
    char smallStr[SIZE] , bigStr[SIZE]; 
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str) ; i++)
    {
        if (str[i]>= 'A' && str[i]<='Z')
        {
            bigStr[countbig] = str[i];
            countbig++;
        }
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            smallStr[countsmall] = str[i];
            countsmall++;
        }
    }
        bigStr[countbig] ='\0'; //you need to add null character at the end 
        smallStr[countsmall] = '\0';//you need to add null character at the end
    puts(smallStr);
    puts(bigStr);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```